# java object serialization for hosting on aws tomcat elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

We are migrating a java based web application built in spring and hibernate to AWS elastic beanstalk.

To manage sessions, we are using the AmazonDynamoDBSessionManagerForTomcat library.
This will typically serialize the session object and store the same in dynamo db.

Now, I have more than 100 beans. Some of them are to be saved in the session during runtime.

I had to implement Serializable to these beans for them to get stored in dynamo db.

Now, I have two options, go through the entire application logic and only implement Serializable to those beans which are stored in the session OR blindly implement Serializable to all the beans (quicker).

Will there be any issues if I choose the later approach ?

Does implementing Serializable to objects that need not be serialized, create any problems ?

Thanks,
Sanket

Comment: There is no problem in making all classes Serializable. It wont create any problem that I can think of.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: From Wikipedia `The serialized state of an object forms part of its class's compatibility contract. Maintaining compatibility between versions of serializable classes requires additional effort and consideration. Therefore, making a class serializable needs to be a deliberate design decision and not a default condition.` This is why objects are not serializable by default in java. In your case its fine to mark all beans serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serializable` is an empty interface (the [*marker pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)) so I don't see any reason not to implement it by all relevant beans.

Make sure that every implementing class has an empty (no args) constructor.